# Getting started with Caliburn.Micro - where is the 'Bootstrapper' class referenced in the documentation?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am trying to use the Caliburn.Micro framework.
However the first page of the [documentation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration,%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) refers to a class that doesn't exist anywhere, called Bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike other versions of Caliburn Micro the WinRT version doesn't use a Bootstrapper, the non ranty reason for this is that Windows.UI.Xaml.Application exposes most of it's functionality through method overrides and not events. Therefore it makes sense to have a custom Application rather than forcing the developer to wire the application to the bootstrapper.

This quote is taken from the documentation on [**Working with WinRT**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20WinRT&referringTitle=Documentation) from the official wiki documentation.

You can look at the complete list of [**documentation wikis**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation) at the official site at Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the WinRT version of Caliburn.Micro where there is no bootstrapper type.

I found [this WinRT-specific tutorial](http://www.terrymarshall.com.au/Blog/tabid/162/EntryId/158/WinRT-and-Caliburn-Micro-Part-2-Getting-Started.aspx) that covers things: